# How to group time for the same weekday?

Tags: javascript

I have a question and get stuck to group the time for the weekday? Could anyone please help me? Thanks

This is the input

```
var array = [{
    monday: true,
    tuesday: true,
    wednesday: true,
    thursday: false,
    friday: false,
    startTime: "10:00",
    endTime: "10:45"
  },
  {
    monday: false,
    tuesday: true,
    wednesday: true,
    thursday: false,
    friday: false,
    startTime: "11:00",
    endTime: "13:00"
  },
  {
    monday: true,
    tuesday: true,
    wednesday: true,
    thursday: false,
    friday: false,
    startTime: "11:00",
    endTime: "12:00"
  },
  {
    monday: true,
    tuesday: true,
    wednesday: true,
    thursday: true,
    friday: true,
    startTime: "8:00"
    endTime: "9:00",
  },
  {
    monday: true,
    tuesday: true,
    wednesday: true,
    thursday: false,
    friday: false,
    startTime: "6:00",
    endTime: "8:00"
  },
  {
    monday: false,
    tuesday: true,
    wednesday: true,
    thursday: false,
    friday: false,
    startTime: "18:00",
    endTime: "19:00"
  }
];
```

This is the output

```
var result = [
  {
    weekday: "Monday - Wednesday", 
    time: ["6:00 - 8:00", "10:00 - 10:45", "11:00 - 12:00" ]   
  },
  {
    weekday: "Tuesday - Wednesday", 
    time: ["11:00 - 13:00", "18:00 - 19:00" ]   
  },
  {
    weekday: "Tuesday - Friday", 
    time: ["8:00 - 9:00"]   
  },
];
```

Comment: Can you show us anything you've already tried?

Comment: In your example output, all of the days are contiguous (so that there is only a single logical range). What should the output look like if the days are non-contiguous (e.g. mon, wed, fri are true, but others are false)

Comment: @Simon - I am still thinking the logic to do it, but not come up with one yet.   

 If the days are non-contiguous, it stand alone. 
e.g, mon, wed, fri are true, but others are false, we will have 

{weekday: "monday, wednesday, friday" , 
 time: [....]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```js
var input = [{ monday: true, tuesday: true, wednesday: true, thursday: false, friday: false, startTime: "10:00", endTime: "10:45" }, { monday: false, tuesday: true, wednesday: true, thursday: false, friday: false, startTime: "11:00", endTime: "13:00" }, { monday: true, tuesday: true, wednesday: true, thursday: false, friday: false, startTime: "11:00", endTime: "12:00" }, { monday: true, tuesday: true, wednesday: true, thursday: true, friday: true, startTime: "8:00", endTime: "9:00", }, { monday: true, tuesday: true, wednesday: true, thursday: false, friday: false, startTime: "6:00", endTime: "8:00" }, { monday: false, tuesday: true, wednesday: true, thursday: false, friday: false, startTime: "18:00", endTime: "19:00" } ];

let result = [];

input.forEach(x => {
   let keys = [];
   Object.entries(x)
         .filter(([key, value]) => value === true)
         .forEach(([key, value]) => keys.push(key));
   let newWeekDay = keys[0] + " - " + keys[keys.length - 1];  
   let interval = [x.startTime + " - " + x.endTime]; 
   if (result.find(j => j.weekday === newWeekDay)) {
     result = result.map(z => {
        if (z.weekday === newWeekDay) z.time.push(...interval);
        return z;
     })
   }
   else result.push({ weekday: newWeekDay, time: interval });
})

console.log(result);
```

In brief:

1. find keys with value as `true`;
2. collect `interval` date;
3. add `interval` if `weekday` is already present in `result` array or create a new object and push it into array.

Comment: wow. It worked. Thanks. I am digesting your logic now.

Comment: @AnNice no problem. Have a nice coding =)

Comment: @AnNice I rewrote logic in a better way. Bye =)

Comment: Your code works fine for a range of weekday. There is another scenario, when I have an object that wednesday: true that has only 1 time slot, the other object has wednesday: true and friday: true . 

It should be printing wednesday for 2 timeslot, and the other Friday will have 1 timeslot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following approach.

Convert days to numbers first using a map. Monday is 0. Friday is 4.

```
For each entry in your input array.
    - Maintain the start and end indices of every contiguous segment which has true values.
    - Push the indices pair to a map container where the key is indices pair and value is array list of time ranges.
```

Iterate over map container by keys and construct the desired format of the result object

Edit: Added a snippet to show the idea

```js
const data = [{
  monday: true,
  tuesday: true,
  wednesday: true,
  thursday: false,
  friday: false,
  startTime: "10:00",
  endTime: "10:45"
}, {
  monday: false,
  tuesday: true,
  wednesday: true,
  thursday: false,
  friday: false,
  startTime: "11:00",
  endTime: "13:00"
}, {
  monday: true,
  tuesday: true,
  wednesday: true,
  thursday: false,
  friday: false,
  startTime: "11:00",
  endTime: "12:00"
}, {
  monday: true,
  tuesday: true,
  wednesday: true,
  thursday: true,
  friday: true,
  startTime: "8:00",
  endTime: "9:00",
}, {
  monday: true,
  tuesday: true,
  wednesday: true,
  thursday: false,
  friday: false,
  startTime: "6:00",
  endTime: "8:00"
}, {
  monday: false,
  tuesday: true,
  wednesday: true,
  thursday: false,
  friday: false,
  startTime: "18:00",
  endTime: "19:00"
}];

const process = (data) => {
  const days = {
    "monday": 1,
    "tuesday": 2,
    "wednesday": 3,
    "thursday": 4,
    "friday": 5
  };
  const result = {};
  data.map((record) => {
    const recordedDays = Object.keys(record)
          .map((key) => record[key] === true ? days[key] : null)
          .filter(Boolean).sort((a, b) => a - b);
    const interval = record.startTime + " - " + record.endTime;
    const indices = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < recordedDays.length; i++) {
      if (i === 0 || i === recordedDays.length - 1 || recordedDays[i + 1] - recordedDays[i] > 1)
          indices.push(recordedDays[i]);
    }
    if (result[indices]) {
      result[indices].push(interval);
    } else {
      result[indices] = [interval];
    }
  });
  return result;
}

const output = (input) => {
  const days = {
    1: "monday",
    2: "tuesday",
    3: "wednesday",
    4: "thursday",
    5: "friday"
  };
  return Object.entries(input).map((data) => {
    const interval = data[0];
    const times = data[1];
    const weekdays = interval.split(",").map((v) => days[v]).join(" - ");
    return {
      weekdays,
      times
    }
  });
}
console.log(output(process(data)));
```

Comment: I still did not get it

Comment: I shall add a code snippet hoping it helps to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

@Giovanni Esposito

Your logic is awesome. It works for a day range. There is a scenario where you have separated day.

I don't know how I cannot put my code in the comment. So I post here. e.g.

8.15.2021

Besides day range already resolved as above, I added this piece of code. Even though It does not separate them to combine with other common weekday, It will group time based on a single weekday, and if there is no consecutive multiple days, it will put a comma for broken weekday (e.g monday, friday). I would like to add this for reference.

````
   [{
    monday: false,
    tuesday: false,
    wednesday: true,
    thursday: false,
    friday: false,
    startTime: "18:00",
    endTime: "19:00"
  },
  {
    monday: false,
    tuesday: false,
    wednesday: true,
    thursday: false,
    friday: true,
    startTime: "20:00",
    endTime: "21:00"
  }]

The output should be printed as 
    { 
      weekday: 'wednesday',
      time: [18:00 - 19:00', '20:00 - 21:00']
    }, 
    { weekday: 'friday',
      time: ['20:00 - 21:00']
    }, 
    } 



let newWeekDay;
 if (keys[0] === keys[keys.length - 1]) {
     newWeekDay = keys[0];  
 } 
 else if (master.join(',').includes(keys.join(','))) {
    newWeekDay = keys[0] + " - " + keys[keys.length - 1];
 }
 else {
     newWeekDay =  keys.join(', ');  
 }```
````